# Digital output high voltage specification

Tags: voltage, digital-logic, integrated-circuit, output

I am using the HD74LS14P (Schmitt trigger inverter IC.)

The datasheet show that VOH is 2.7 V (for  VCC = 4.75 V.)  My IC gives me about 4.5 V when VI=0 V.

I need my IC to give the right value.

I am using a Rasberry Pi which uses 3.3V as input voltage.

[image]

Comment: The output range is always from the minimum and the applied VCC. You can lower it with diodes, a resistor divider or a voltage translator, depending on the performance you need.

Answer (score 4):

The chip guarantees that it will output *at least* 2.7 Volts for a "high" output. It doesn't state anything about the maximum voltage that it can output - it may go all the way up to 5 Volts (the supply voltage). In fact, if you look at the part of the datasheet that you've circled in red, you'll see that there is no value given for the typical / maximum output voltage.

If you need to translate a 5V signal to 3.3V levels, you have to use a chip with so-called *5V-tolerant* inputs and run it off 3.3V. An example of such a chip is the 74LCX14.

Alternatively, you could use a 74HCT14 and divide its output voltage with a simple resistive voltage divider. And as Neil_UK suggested, you could also clamp the 74LS14's output voltage, i.e. with a blue LED or a zener diode.

Comment: Is there any way to use my Ic and have 3.3v , I know the level shifter will be a solution , but i want more less complicated circuit, Is the tension divider will be a solution for my case ?!

Comment: @Oussama   If by 'tension divider' you mean a two-resistor voltage divider, probably not. An LS device has a poorly defined output high voltage. You might do well to clamp the output to ground with a 3 V (ish ) (so blue or white) LED. As you can see, the output current **is** defined, and is quite low. LS is unusual in this respect, don't do this with CMOS.

Comment: The output voltage of 74LS chips varies too much for you to be able to use a voltage divider. It'd work with a 74HCT14 and a voltage divider, though. Neil also made a very good point with the voltage clamp.

Answer (score 2):

It is not unexpected.

The datasheet **guarantees** that voltage is **at least** 2.7V when the chip is driving out 400uA into the load. Voltage will be much higher, near the supply voltage, when there is no load at all.

Chips supplied with 5V are not suitable to drive inputs which tolerate only 3.3V.